# Create an RSS feed of all posts

Tags: rss, feed

I'm fairly new to Wordpress and I'm just wondering how to create a RSS feed of all posts.

Are there plugins for this?  Is this something I have to change in code? etc...

I'm trying to implement my Wordpress posts with `Hootsuite`, so that when I make new posts in Wordpress, `Hootsuite` will automatically post them on my social media websites through RSS.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Check this out [WordPress Feeds](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds)

Answer (score 2):

WordPress already [automatically creates RSS feeds](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds) ... just add `/feed/` to the end of a URL

you can do this from  `topleveldomain.com/feed`  or and even from categories and tags  like this `topleveldomain.com/tag/sometag/feed`

You should also go to WordPRess Admin > Settings > Reading and you may need to change the number of default items in your feed from 10 to 20 or more.

see also the page on the WordPress codex referenced by Amit in the comment above.

Comment: I must be screwing something up then.  I have the plugin `FeedWordPress` to help pull in other peoples feeds. I manage this content in a custom content type.  When I append `/feed/` it for some reason is pulling all of these feed items instead of my default blog posts.

Comment: Hi there - that's a completely different question / topic. I use 'feedwordpress' and what it does is publish syndicated content as new posts to your blog. This is why the RSS feed includes others content. Try a feed with just your authored content like `damien.co/author/damiensaunders/feed/`